# Bootstrap popover with grid item that change on click

Tags: javascript, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm trying to create a dynamic content using JavaScript, DOM and Array in bootstrap.
Here is the idea: We have a static image and text (note that the text is allow or goes just with "this" image) clicking anywhere on the area (where the image and the text is) shows a popover. This popover contains Grid of item that are display with different image and different text. Clicking on this images changes the static images. Exp: clicking on the area that contains image 2 text 2 changes the image 1 text 1 to image 2 text 2.
I'm stock on trying to create a grid content that react on click event inside the popover field.

Any ideas, Anythings that can help me will be welcome.
Forgot to mention i'm new in bootstrap and i'm also a beginner in JS. But i'm a good programmer (Java, Python, Haskel, C#...)

Since i'm new here, can't post code or image please leave me a message for more details.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The format here typically requires that you make an effort and ask very specific questions when you have a problem. Your question is very general and not a good fit. Best of luck. P.s. You can post code. Format it using the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

I've used popovers in bootstrap and they can be tricky to format. First reference

[This documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-usage)

It is very important you include the attribute data-html="true" otherwise it will be impossible to format content within the popover.  Here's also a working [demo](http://triplewww.com/cm/bs/base_popover.html).

Here is also a working [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/rMdLZ/6/)

Your code should be something like this. Hope this works for you!

jQuery

```
$(function ()
 { $(".tip").popover();
 });

//HIDES POPOVER ON CLICK OUTSIDE

 $('html').on('mouseup', function(e) {
if(!$(e.target).closest('.popover').length) {
    $('.popover').each(function(){
        $(this.previousSibling).popover('hide');
    });
  }
});
```

HTML

```
    <div ><a href="#" class="tip" rel="popover" data-trigger="click"  data-html="true" 
    data-content="Yadda Yadda.<P><P><P><P>More stuff on another line" 
   data-original-title="Your popover title">
   <span style="cursor:pointer;">Text and images here</span></a></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you help! 
But i actually want to change the data-content and use a grid system to display onclick image and text.
I alrady settle the popover. But i want to change the content of the popover so that it show up a grid of pictures and text insteed of just text. I've been working on it for days now. And i think i'll not go any further without help. So any help will be welcome. 
Thanks!